# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch3d.io' in colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I was running this Google Colab today everything was working fine but eventually I starting getting these errors in the Set Up Environment. I can't find a fix. Any help would be appreciated let me know if I need to provide more info.

Here is the link for the colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15-vJXyGQvfMSOgPneQqwNyrBh5rnBaV-?usp=sharing

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-84909fa89079> in <cell line: 48>()
     46 clear_output()
     47 #render video
---> 48 from lib.colab_util import generate_video_from_obj, set_renderer, video
     49 
     50 renderer = set_renderer()

/content/pifuhd/lib/colab_util.py in <module>
     33 
     34 # Util function for loading meshes
---> 35 from pytorch3d.io import load_objs_as_meshes
     36 
     37 from IPython.display import HTML

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch3d.io'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

- First please open the access on the Notebook to gain deeper
  understanding.
- second try to uninstall and reinstall it from github with commands

  !pip install ‘git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/pytorch3d.git'

Comment: If you see the above example the issue is with pytorch3d.io

Comment: I have made the url to public. Thanks

Comment: sorry for that, I have edited the answer , hope it can help.

Comment: I have updated the same in my colab. But still I am having the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch3d'. New code can be found in my colab